# How to save the number of votes on a poll on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, database, file

I am writing a VERY basic website to learn some javascript, I want a poll to be displayed when you load the page, eg what is your favourite ice cream, then the user clicks a button for their corresponding choice. I then want this to increment a counter somewhere stored on the server, which will be accessible on another page for users to see all of the results. I am stuck finding a way to store the vote on the server, having never used javascript before (the only thing comparable is extensive Python, where writing to file is very easy) I am unable to find a way to do this.

My current train of thought is something like this,

```
<ul class="pollList">
      <li onclick="vote(1)">Chocolate</li>
      <li onclick="vote(1)">Vanilla</li>
      <li onclick="vote(1)">Mint Choc Chip</li>
      <li onclick="vote(1)">Strawberry</li>
</ul>
```

but I have no idea what to write on the javascript side.

Comment: You need to use a back end language because you need to store the data in a database. JavaScript cannot do this because it's a front end language and can't communicate with the database. Examples of back-end languages are PHP, ASP, .NET, Python, etc. You also need MySql for the Database

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+click+ajax+python+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: How can I get the two to interact though? I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious but I see no way of getting a button in HTML to interact with a Python script.

Comment: Ajax. Use jQuery or fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you've heard of Ajax.. this is the right place where you can use it.

Ajax helps you perform an GET or POST action directly from your page view

Here's how you can do it,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $(".pollList li").click(function () { 

         $.ajax({
           url: "url", 
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'value1', email: 'value2' }),
           success: function (result) {
               // when call is sucessfull
            },
            error: function (err) {
            // check the err for error details
            }
         }); // ajax call closing

      });
   });
```

in url pass the respective post method path
in data pass the respective id to vote
store the data (using backend languages such as PHP, Python or something else) in your database on server and done

**Note:**
Yes as @mplungjan mentioned in comments you do need Jquery Ajax libraries to perform the operation

You can also achieve this solution using html Forms action and PHP for backend. give it a try

Comment: Please 1. Use the code OP has and 2. Mention your code needs the jQuery libraries

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this, where does this go? What language is this?

Comment: @Jake it's Jquery Ajax script, which helps you store the data on server without refreshing the current page